# Color Rows In DataGridView

Tags: c#, performance

I am using the below syntax to color code sales persons data.  The issue that I have is that the datagridview returns roughly 12,000 rows so the coloring syntax takes some extensive time to execute.

Is there a way to optimize this code?

```
private void datagridview1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["Jake"].Value == System.DBNull.Value && row.Cells["Jones"].Value == System.DBNull.Value && row.Cells["Lati"].Value == System.DBNull.Value && row.Cells["Venitia"].Value == System.DBNull.Value)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }            
}
private void PopulateIT()
{
    datagridview1.Visible = true;
    lblNoData.Visible = false;

    string connString = @"Connection String";
    string query = @"SELECT * from tempdata";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(formattedDT);
    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
    datagridview1.DataSource = formattedDT;
    datagridview1.AutoResizeColumns();
}
```

Comment: We need to see more of the code. What is filling up the `DataGridView datagridview1` in the first place?

Comment: @Snowbody - see edit.  This is how I am populating the datagridview

Comment: Iterating over each cell in the datagridview is going to be time consuming, especially if your datagridview really contains that many rows.  Could you possibly use DefaultCellStyle to change the Background Color?

Comment: I am surprised you don't need to define formattedDT

Comment: @Paparazzi - formattedDT is defined and instantiated at a diff place in my code.  To avoid over filling my post with code I only showed the lines that are causing my issues.

Comment: Cool but you should post code that will stand on its own

Comment: How many time is datagridview1_CellFormatting called?  Are you possibly formatting each row multiple times?

Comment: @Paparazzi -> no it is not called multiple times.  It is only called once, but the issue seems to be the foreach loop is time consuming

Comment: Are you sure as that is not what the documentation states?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellformattingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx    The CellFormatting event occurs every time each cell is painted, so you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event.

Comment: from stepping thro the code, it seems to me that the datatable is bound to the datagridview then the _CellFormatting method is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are implementing the `IDisposable` interface. Enclosing the usage of these objects inside a `using` statement ensures that the objects will always be proper disposed because the `using` statement just equals a `try...finally` where the objects would be disposed in the `finally` part.

The main problem regarding your performance issue is, that by calling the `AutoResizeColumns()` method the event will be triggered for **each row and each column**.
This results for each row and each column that you iterate over **every row in the DataGridView**.

So if we assume you have 12,000 rows with at least 5 columns .... you can do the math yourself.

The `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` has a property `RowIndex` which allows to access a single row so you should use this.

Summing this up in some code could look like so

```
private bool shouldFormattingBeDone = false;
private void PopulateIT()
{
    datagridview1.Visible = true;
    lblNoData.Visible = false;

    string connString = @"Connection String";
    string query = @"SELECT * from tempdata";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(formattedDT);
    }
    datagridview1.DataSource = formattedDT;

    shouldFormattingBeDone = false;
    datagridview1.AutoResizeColumns();
    shouldFormattingBeDone = true;
}


private void datagridview1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (shouldFormattingBeDone == false) { return; }

    DataGridViewRow row = datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    if (row.Cells["Jake"].Value == System.DBNull.Value && row.Cells["Jones"].Value == System.DBNull.Value && row.Cells["Lati"].Value == System.DBNull.Value && row.Cells["Venitia"].Value == System.DBNull.Value)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

}
```

This could be beautified by having an extension method which takes a `DataGridViewCell` as a parameter like so

```
public static class DataGridViewExtension
{
    public static bool IsDbNull(this DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        return cell.Value == DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

resulting in  the `if` condition looking like so

```
if (row.Cells["Jake"].IsDbNull() && row.Cells["Jones"].IsDbNull() && row.Cells["Lati"].IsDbNull() && row.Cells["Venitia"].IsDbNull())
```

PS: I can't remember if the connection needs to be open when the constructor of the `SqlDataAdapter` is called.

Comment: I LOVE the extension class you created DataGridViewExtension - makes the code much more readable and cleaner!  This cut the execution down to < 3 minutes, whereas before I was hitting 15 minutes and the execution was still not complete!

Comment: In a comment OP claimed datagridview1_CellFormatting is only called once.

Comment: @Paparazzi which just isn't true

Comment: Agree but that is what the OP claimed.  Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like that repeated code pattern in the `if...DbNull &&...` . I think the field names should be stored in an array/list and then you could do something LINQy like

```
if (fieldNamesList.All(fieldName=>row.Cells[fieldName].IsDbNull()))
```

That way it would be easier to add and remove field names without having to make error prone copy and paste, also the line is shorter.

Also I hope that in your actual code, instead of this stripped-down version, the connection string is read from a config store instead of being hardcoded.